# (SOLIDITY) Address in mapping - BUG?

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping, bug

> Original post:
>
> [image: original post]

Sorry I just found out this way it actually works. But the problem is when I trying to look up address manually, not by msg.sender.

**Code:**

```
mapping (address => uint) count;

function set() public{
    count[address(0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe)] = 3;
}

function get(address _address) public view returns(uint){
    return count[_address];
}
```

I called *set* function and when I pasted the same address into *get* function the result was 0.

[image: Smart contract screenshot]

**Debug:**

[image: Debug screenshot]

Comment: You should add your source code

Comment: The 20-byte address code would be packed into a 32-byte word, possibly with other data depending on the contract and what the compiler decides to do with it. It's not clear why you're working at this level or why it's a problem, when Solidity will happily decode it for you. Please include your contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the address in the field with quotation marks "0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe"

It works for me.